# Conditional density calculation

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, density-function

If we know the density of a vector $x$ is $f(x)$, which could be multivariate standard normal $N(0,I_r)$, and we know the conditional density of $f(y|x)$, which is multivariate normal $N(Ax,I_T)$ with $A$ being a $A \times r$ matrix with $T>r$. My question is how to derive the conditional density $f(x|y)$. Any suggestions or reference? Thanks

Comment: Ummm... use Bayes Rule, perhaps?

Comment: I am not from statistics, I checked some books, it shows $f(x|y)=f(x,y)/f(y）$,but how to derive $f(y)$? Thanks

Comment: You don't have to be "from statistics" to use Bayes Rule, which explains how to find $f(y)$.

Comment: From the textbook, I know $f(x,y)=f(y|x)f(x)$. but in order to derive $f(x|y)$, I need $f(y)$. Do I need to integral over $x$ in $f(y|x)$ to get $f(y)$?